# Troubles with Xephyr and Steam games

Tags: drivers, xorg, display-resolution, steam, amdgpu

[Using Kubuntu 20.04, clean install. Also tried with Kubuntu 19.10 prior. Same errors]

I am trying to run a steam game in a nested x-session, to automate the game while still having control over my mouse. I tried various approaches, but can't get it to open on Xephyr. Also tried xpra and had the same errors. 
I was running:

`Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1600x900 :1 &`

and then various ways to start steam in display :1. 
When I run steam in Xephyr's x-session, I get a lot of errors but the app shows up and seems to function normally, but any game that I try to run inside it does not show up at all.

The error in the screen: 
"Couldn't switch to requested monitor resolution"
"Details: 
Switching to resolution 800x588 failed, trying lower one
All resolution switches have failed
Screen: DX11 could not switch resolution (960x588 fs=0 hz=0)"

This is using Steam's proton, but it runs normally on my main display. No errors whatsoever. 
I tried a lot of resolutions on Xephyr and the error is always the same, only changing the "switching to resolution xxx" part.

The errors I get on the console are very big: 
https://pastebin.com/6djNgYd1

I have tried changing the xorg.config file for my AMD gpu also but it seems to make no difference. My Xorg version is 1.20, so DRI 3 should be enabled by default as per amdgpu manual.

For my overall objective (automating a game without using my own mouse), a nested X-session seemed the most promising but it has been a lot of trouble. Would appreciate suggestions and any kind of help. Thank you very much.

Edit: Just found out that starting steam from main display now also has a lot of console output, but it still works with no errors. And game too. 
Steam console output: https://pastebin.com/iWb7fSb3

Edit2: Tried with clean install ubuntu 20.04. Same exact error. I think the problem is Xephyr (and xpra) doesn't run with dri3, and it is necessary for vulkan (steam's proton)... Couldn't enable it

Comment: Can you disable fullscreen mode in this game?

Comment: the game doesn't have fullscreen mode, the lowest resolution is 960x600. I have tested with all others also

Comment: AFAIU it tries to change desktop resolution, how is that not a fullscreen mode? Is there anything about windowed mode in settings?

Comment: @int_ua I also do not understand the error. The game doesn't even have a fullscreen mode, it defaults to 960x600. I have also tried with another game, which has a windowed mode but it is the exactly same error, windowed or not. 

I think I narrowed down the problem to Xephyr lacking the DRI tho, if you could help, I made another question with more specific info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235354/x-server-does-not-have-dri-enabled

Comment: I have tried Galcon game and it launched normally. However, I have trouble with Detroit Become Human. See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650156/trick-a-window-that-it-has-focus-in-kde/650162