# X server does not have DRI enabled

Tags: drivers, xorg, xserver, amdgpu, xorg.conf

I have recently asked another question here regarding problems with running steam games in a nested X session with Xephyr. I think now that I have narrowed down the problem to the X server not having DRI enabled.

The command

```bsh
xdpyinfo | grep DRI
```

does not show anything.

In my main display, it shows both DRI 2 and DRI 3.

On the other hand, `glxinfo` shows:

```
name of display: :1
display: :1 screen: 0  
direct rendering: Yes
```

I'm using a RX480 gpu with i7 3770k cpu on an Ubuntu 20.04 clean install.

My `xorg.conf` is:

```
10-amdgpu.conf
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "AMDgpu"
    MatchDriver "amdgpu"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

Comment: I guess that Xephyr doesn't support DRI and it's somehow related to the fact that Xephyr [doesn't have GLX support](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/).

Comment: I couldn't make it run... Turned out I could run the game through a web browser and that worked for the session, but now I have another problem. If you would kindly see if you can help me with this issue as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235762/random-black-screens-in-nested-x-server 
thank you for all answers.