# Random black screens in nested X server

Tags: xorg, xserver, amdgpu

I am running a X nested session with Xephyr to automate a game. I need the screen to be on at all times. I have disabled ubuntu sleep timer and it seems to be working for the whole pc but the nested X server goes to a black screen randomly. I don't know what is causing it. It happened one time overnight (after hours working perfectly) and two times when testing today.

I run the server with
`Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -resizeable -softCursor -screen 1800x800 :1 &`
I then run my terminal
`DISPLAY=:1 alacritty`
and inside the X session I run:
`openbox &` the only window manager I got to run
`firefox -noremote -P MyProfile &` where I run the game
and then I use python scripts to automate it with pyautogui, which needs the screen to be on, and breaks when it gets black randomly.

Happened one time during my writing this. If I move my mouse over the X session it goes back to working normally.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?